# Flag rows by number of consequent occurrences in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

I am new in R and I have been struggling with a conditional I want to apply in a data.table.

My data.table which is ordered by Order_id and Date, looks like this.[image: this]

What I need is to create a new column with a flagger variable with these conditions:

- If there are more than 3 consecutive 0 in hours_delta column then mark these lines and the line before with flag_1
- If there are less than 3 and more than 1 consecutive 0 in hours_delta
  then mark these lines and the line before with flag_2
- If there is only one 0 between two that are more than 0 like in line index[8] then mark these lines with flag_3
- Mark all the rest with flag_4

This is how I want the table to look like after the new column.[image: this]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What if there are exacty 3 zeros between non-zero values?

Comment: Also could you please clarify what is meant by *less than 3 and more than 1* . In terms of algebra is it [1,3], (1,3], [1,3) or (1,3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really great response @Matt Jewett! Thanks for an awesome answer. This answer is in response to @oikonang's comment above who noticed correctly that this solution doesn't work if there are consecutive groups of 0's in the same Order_id.

To fix this here is some rudimentary code that can be included in @Matt Jewett's code above:

```
rle = unlist(sapply(1:length(rle(hours_delta)[[1]]), function(r) {
  if (rle(hours_delta)[[2]][r] == 0) {
     rep(rle(hours_delta)[[1]][r],rle(hours_delta)[[1]][r]) 
  } else {
  rep(NA, rle(hours_delta)[[1]][r]) }
}))
```

This should be included in place of the

```
ifelse(hours_delta == 0,rle(hours_delta)[[1]][rle(hours_delta)[[2]] == 0],NA)
```

line above.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this might work for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create test dataframe
index <- c(0:19)
Order_id <- c(rep(001,8),rep(002,3),rep(003,4),rep(004,3),rep(005,2))
hours_delta <- c(720,552,rep(0,5),432,0,72,96,121,0,0,0,33,0,0,77,0)

df <- data.frame(index,Order_id,hours_delta)


# Start dplyr modifications
df <- df %>%
      # Group data by Order_id
      group_by(Order_id) %>%
      # Get the number of repitions of 0 for in the hours_delta field for that Order_id
      mutate(rle = ifelse(hours_delta == 0,rle(hours_delta)[[1]][rle(hours_delta)[[2]] == 0],NA),
             # Set the row above a zero sequence to the number of repetitions
             rle = ifelse(is.na(rle),lead(rle),rle)) %>%
      # ungroup the data
      ungroup() %>%
      # Set the flags based on number of repetitions
      mutate(flagger = case_when(is.na(.$rle)
                                 ~ "flag_4",
                                 .$rle == 1
                                 ~ "flag_3",
                                 (.$rle <= 3 & .$rle > 1)
                                 ~ "flag_2",
                                 .$rle > 3
                                 ~ "flag_1"
                                )
             ) %>%
     # Remove the temporary rle column
     select(-rle)
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it possible to apply the same functionality to data.tables? I mean, instead of using pipes and rle() function, what is the adequate result in data.table format. The problem is that it works when I apply it on a sample data frame but I get totally different results when I apply the code to the main data.table. Is it wise to convert the whole data.table to a data.frame just to apply the above and then back to data.table?

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. Try to apply the same by just replacing the Order_id with `Order_id <- c(rep(001,8)) `. So if there are multiple consecutive countings of 0 for the same Order_id it messes up. Is there a way out of this?